# Create vault matter and export mailboxes with GAM

Tags: command-line-interface, google-apps, google-workspace, google-vault-api

So, I'm new to [GAM](https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM) but was tasked by my supervisor to use it with our Google Workspace to create a process of exporting offboarded employee mailboxes on a regular basis. I've learned a bit about Google Vault and think that I know what I need to do.

1. Create a vault matter that searches for the mailbox of a specified user.
2. Export the findings of the newly created matter.
3. Download the export as a PST or MBOX file.

In theory, I'd like to write a script to do this for all offboarded employees once a week but have had trouble with step 1 while testing.

I've tried:

```
> gam create matter "Users Mailbox" corpus mail accounts user@mycompany.com   

> ERROR: Users Mailbox is not a valid argument for "gam create matter"


> gam create vaultexport | export matter "Offboarded Employees" corpus mail accounts user@mycompany.com

export: not valid in this context: Offboarded Employees
 
ERROR: you must specify a matter for the new export.

[1]    exit 3     gam create vaultexport
```

I have installed GAM version 6.08 and am using the below resources.

- [GAM Cheat Sheet](https://gamcheatsheet.com/GAM%20Cheat%20Sheet%20A3.pdf)
- [GAM Commands](https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM/blob/main/src/GamCommands.txt)

Maybe I'm just misunderstanding the syntax and need another set of eyes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

Checking this documentation:

- [Google Vault Commands in GAM](https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM/wiki/Google-Vault-Commands#creating-matters)

The syntax used is:

> gam create vaultmatter name "Testing" description "This is a test"

I tried using the syntax that you mentioned above and got the same error message:

> ERROR: Testing is not a valid argument for "gam create matter"

What I checked is that the "name" of the vault matter was not included in your syntax so most likely "Users mailbox" is being recognized as an argument when you don't identify it as the name of the matter.

I would suggest as well that you download the latest version in GAM:
https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM/releases